# Why git push behaves like git push --force?

Tags: git, git-push

Why does `git push` result in *forced update*, causing lost commits on the origin? 
What can be done to prevent this?

- client side: git version 1.8.2.2
- `push.default` set to `simple`
- server side: gitlab  5.1.0 4854087

Based on some searching it is probably connected to the `+` sign in `remote.origin.fetch` setting, but when i clone a fresh repo, the `+` sign is already there (so it's not caused by me messing with the repo).

Comment: `remote.origin.push` is being set automatically?  I don't think that's true.  `remote.origin.fetch` is the one that's there by default.  You probably need to fix your `.push` refspec and remove the `+`.

Comment: You don't have any 'mirror' settings in the config?

Comment: Ah - found one ``mirror=true`` entry. How did it get there?

Comment: @liborm, by using `--mirror` when doing `git clone` or `git remote add`, for instance.  Direct invocation of `git config` is another possible way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you saw in the [config the `.mirror` option](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), then it makes sense that a git push overrides everything:

```
remote.<name>.mirror
```

> If true, pushing to this remote will automatically behave as if the `--mirror` option was given on the command line.

You can do it with `git config remote.backup.mirror true`.

If you have access to the remote repo settings, then you could do a:

```
git config receive.denyNonFastForwards true
```

in order to prevent those forced push.

But this isn't [yet supported on a remote repo like GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13016552/6309) for instance.